# Raspberry Pi GPIO safe clean up

Tags: python, python-2.x, raspberry-pi

We are always told to call `GPIO.cleanup()` before we exit our Pi programs. I've seen people using `try ... catch ... finally` to achieve this. But hey, we are doing python here, an elegant programming language. Do you guys think this is a more elegant solution?

```
# SafeGPIO.py

from RPi import GPIO

class SafeGPIO(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return GPIO

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Use like this:

```
from SafeGPIO import SafeGPIO
import time

with SafeGPIO() as GPIO:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(7, True)
    GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(8, True)

    val = 0
    for i in xrange(10):
        val = (val + 1) % 2
        active_pin = 7 + val
        inactive_pin = 7 + (val + 1) % 2
        GPIO.output(active_pin,True)
        GPIO.output(inactive_pin,False)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the code in your questions after receiving answers is against site policy. See [What do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: Just to state that, the purpose of creating this context manager is not just to ensure `cleanup` on exit, but to ensure `cleanup` when program exits the `with` block. We might need to use `cleanup`multiple times. Whereas `at_exit ` only run once on program exit.

Comment: I have also created a decorator for this purpose, available [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113605/raspberry-pi-safe-clean-up-the-decorator-way)

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively I think that I don't like to encapsulate all of my program in a `with SafeGPIO() as GPIO` call, so I searched the library and found [at_exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html). Using this you should be able to have something like the following in SafeGPIO.py:

```
import at_exit
from RPi import GPIO as RPi_GPIO

# Something useful to re-export GPIO?! Possibly the following?
GPIO = RPi_GPIO

@atexit.register
def cleanup():
    RPI_GPIO.cleanup()
```

Not sure on how to re-export the GPIO, but if this construct works you only need to do `from SafeGPIO import GPIO`, and then when Python exits it will call the original `GPIO.cleanup()`.

Now the real question is *why don't the `RPi` module automatically do this if this is a best practice when using `RPi`?* Sadly, I don't know the answer to that, but it could be a reason for it, which might affect whether this is actually a good solution or not.

<sub>**PS!** I've addressed some more variants related to how to do cleanup in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113641/78136), where I also focus a little more on choosing different options related to use cases.</sub>

Comment: Well, I'm a programmer, new to Raspberry Pi, but opening pins feels like opening files to me. And in python you use `with open('filename','rb') as myfile:` to wrap around your file read so you always close the file.

Comment: And also, my code is not limited to clean up pins on exit, also u can use it to clean up pins in a function or half way in your code. To avoid wrapping all your code in the `SafeGPIO`, you can have your code in a function, then wrap that function call in `SafeGPIO()`. I like the idea of using a decorator. I will create a decorator version of it as well. Maybe put it up in github.

Comment: Are you sure this is as safe as using `with`? There are exceptions listed there where `at_exit` isn't being called, though admittedly I'm not sure when `with` doesn't call `__exit__` correctly.

Comment: Unless python crashes, otherwise `with` catches all exceptions. That's why they use `with open(...)` to read / write files.

Comment: @rabbit.aaron, I've written an extended version of this answer on your followup question, trying to highlight some of the different aspects of various alternatives.